# What might cause my server to lose network routes?

Tags: networking, 18.04, routing

I'm using a server running Ubuntu to monitor a number of servers in various network zones in my hosting environment. To allow this server to contact all the servers it monitors I manually added a number of routes using `ip route`.

A few days ago my monitoring tools stopped working because all the servers became unreachable. On further investigation, this was because all the routes I'd added to the routing table had disappeared. I've checked `kern.log` and `syslog` and can't see anything unusual at the time connectivity was lost, and this server hasn't restarted since it was first provisioned.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what caused this to happen, or where I could go to get more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably related to the command issued, since it won't apply your routes permanently. I would strongly suggest configuring them via `netplan` for a peristent configuration.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that `ip route add`  wasn't permanent. I'll look into `netplan`.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured this one out. The routes were lost when the DHCP lease was renewed. Even though it received the same IP address, the external routes were still lost. The routes are set through netplan, so I'm not sure why they didn't restore, but that's a problem for another day!